# Recovering dataframe from Rstudio viewer?

Tags: r, rstudio

[image]

Hello, I made a dataframe in an rstudio session named 'pull3'. I then left that session and started a new project. When I went back to the previous session, I can see the dataframe from when I previously used the Viewer() to find it, but it is no longer in the environment variables and I can't seem to download/reference it at all.

It looks like it is stored in data://pull3...does anyone know how to access this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting question! I'll spare you the lecture about the importance of reproducibility and saving your code because I'm curious to know how RStudio stores objects in the viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your project directory you will find a hidden folder called `.Rproj.user`. Further in your directory tree, eventually you will find a folder called `viewer-cache` which contains a `.Rdata` file.

I suspect that the directory names are random, so you'll have to do a little digging. If you're on Linux or MacOS, you might try `find ~/Project | grep ".Rdata"` to speed up the process.

Here's an example of toy data I just saved.

```
Project
└── .Rproj.user
    └── D31E74F4
        └── viewer-cache
            └── 6F635E12.Rdata
```

You can load that `.Rdata` with `load()`:

```
load("~/Project/.Rproj.user/D31E74F4/viewer-cache/6F635E12.Rdata")
```

And there will then be an object with the same name as the file in your global environment:

```
head(`6F635E12`)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

If you are not using a project, you may find the file in `~/.rstudio-desktop/viewer-cache`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Ian's answer, here is a function that returns a list containing all of the objects it recovers.

```
recover_data_viewer_cache_objects <- function() {
  active_project <- rstudioapi::getActiveProject()

  if(is.null(active_project)) {
    if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows")
      viewer_cache_files <- Sys.glob(file.path(Sys.getenv("localappdata"),
                                               "RStudio-Desktop",
                                               "viewer-cache",
                                               "*.Rdata"))
    else
      viewer_cache_files <- Sys.glob(file.path("~",
                                               ".rstudio-desktop",
                                               "viewer-cache",
                                               "*.Rdata"))
  } else {
    viewer_cache_files <- Sys.glob(file.path(active_project,
                                             ".Rproj.user",
                                             "*",
                                             "viewer-cache",
                                             "*.Rdata"))
  }

  # record environment, load cached objects, return environment diff
  # (apply family does not work with base::load() or base::get())
  ls_0 <- ls()
  for(o in viewer_cache_files)
    load(o)
  new_objects <- setdiff(ls(), c(ls_0, "ls_0", "o"))
  recovered_objects <- list()
  for(o in seq_along(new_objects))
    recovered_objects[[new_objects[o]]] <- get(new_objects[o])

  recovered_objects
}
```